# Implementing interface problem after switching from Tomcat 7 to JBoss 4.2.1

Tags: java, jsf-2, tomcat7, jsf-1.2, jboss-4.2.x

I made a Dynamic web project in Eclipse using tomcat 7 (and I used Dynamic web module version 3.0 and JSF 2.0). Now when I had to switch from tomcat 7 to JBoss 4.2.1 it seems there is some kind of compatibility problem because the JBoss doesn't allow Dynamic web module version 3.0 but 2.5 and JSF 1.2 instead of JSF 3.0 that I used. So when I was trying to deploy my old project in new project that will use JBoss this strange error appeared:

I have this `DBManager` class that implements 2 interfaces (`UserManageable` and `CategoryManageable`). In `UserManageable` I have a method `void doInsert(User user)`, `doUpdate(User)`, etc. but eclipse tells me there is a mistake and offers 2 solutions: 1st to remove the `@Override` annotation and 2nd to create `doInsert(User)` in the other interface. If I remove the other interface it just offers me the 1st solution.

Here are the class and the interfaces.

```
import jsfDP.interfaces.CategoryManageable;
import jsfDP.interfaces.UserManageable;

public class DBManager implements UserManageable, CategoryManageable{

    @Override
    public void doInsert(User user) {
        // here I get 
        // The method doInsert(User) of type DBManager must override a superclass method
        // 2 quick fixes available: 
        // Create doInsert() in supertype 'CategoryManageable'
        // Remove '@Override' annotation
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Interface `UserManageable`:

```
import java.util.List;
import jsfDP.beans.User;

public interface UserManageable {
    void doInsert(User user);
    void doUpdate(User user);
    void doDelete(User user);

    User getUserById(int userId);
    List<Integer> getUserIds();
    List<User> getAllUsersInList();
}
```

Interface `CategoryManageable`:

```
package jsfDP.interfaces;

import java.util.List;
import jsfDP.beans.Category;

public interface CategoryManageable {
    List<Category> getCagegories();

}
```

Comment: P.S. I added jsf 1.2 libs to the WEB-INF/lib but still nothing ...

Comment: Thats quite a step back, to have to go from Tomcat 7 to JBoss 4.x

Comment: Yes it is ... but I have to do it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the JBoss with Java 1.5 (and it seems that way), you need to remove the annotation. The `@Override` annotation for interfaces is a Java 6 and later feature.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. 

C:\Users\user>java -version

java version "1.6.0_07"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_07-b06)

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 10.0-b23, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Removing the '@Override' helped and the class is not complaining about interface's methods implementation.